# Travel to Singapore on Cancelled passport

Tags: passports, singapore

I got visa from Singapore with a valid passport having expire date on 1st of Dec 2014. In the meantime I applied for new passport, now passport office stamped as “cancelled” on my existing passport. But still I didn't received my new passport.

My question is that could I visit Singapore with my existing passport which have “cancelled” stamp on it.

Comment: Are you hoping to travel with just the cancelled passport, or with both the old and new ones?

Comment: I think the bottom line is almost certainly "NO".  You can't travel on a cancelled passport.  It's even really hard to "get back somewhere" with a cancelled passport. Note that the visas INSIDE your cancelled passport can be used - often you have to have your current passport AND an old one, because the damned visa is inside the old one.

Comment: Gagravarr, I am planning to travel with old passport (cancelled), i didn't get the new one till yet.

Comment: Yes Joe visa is inside cancelled passport, so waiting for the new one. Just hoping to get the new passport asap, i think there is no option with old passport(cancelled).

Comment: Note that you might be able to get an emergency/temporary passport if you really have to travel while waiting for the new one. You can get one of those usually in a couple of hours.

Answer (score 6):

You can not travel with an cancelled passport irregardless of the former expiration date.  Once they have marked the passport as cancelled it is no lonver a valid document for travel.

The airline will not let you board with an invalid passport, your home country's immigration will likely not let you leave the country and Singapore won't let you in if you somehow overcome the previous two.

Once you have your new passport, then you can use the Singapore visa until its expiration date, by showing both the new and old passport.

Comment: Yes Tom today I just confirmed from Passport office, they too told me the same thing. I need to wait for my new passport, then update my new passport details on visa application, then I will able to go singapore.

Answer (score 0):

I too confirmed from Passport office that the cancelled passport is no longer a valid doc. Too agree with Tom.

Thanks everyone for your valueable comments

Comment: Thanks for coming back to confirm.  If you agree with another answer, please accept it!